# Firestore rules validate query field value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have collection of users and every user can search for others by their `publicId`

```
query(
 collection(db, "users"),
 where("publicId", "==", "..."),
 limit(1)
);
```

and I want to allow users to regenerate their `publicId"s so others won't be able to find them by the old ones.

The problem is that if someone finds a user once and get their doc id they could potentially get the user by that `doc("users", "docId")` regardless of their "publicId".

I tried to use `request.query.publicId == resource.data.publicId`, but `query` seems to only provide `limit`, `offset` and `orderBy`.

Is there a different way to access the query field value or a different way to mitigate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the public profile, it might be best to create another collection e.g. "public_users" where the document ID is user's `publicId`. So when a user regenerates their ID, you can just create another document with new `publicId` and then delete the previous one.

Do not store a reference to user's UID in this document if you want to keep that a secret. Instead, store this public ID in the "users" collection so that can be read by user only.

Alternatively, you can make your requests through a Cloud Function and block direct requests to Firestore. So there's no way anyone can query by user ID.

---

For the main collection, you can add a rule that allows users to write their own document only like this:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

---

Comment: This I already have. What I need is for users to be invisible/private unless you have their latest  "publicId".

Comment: @VeselinIvanov I misread the question initially, can you check the updated question ?